# Is it halal to pay riba with riba?

Tags: riba, finance, loan

Instead of sending unwanted income from riba towards charity, would it be halal to use the earned riba to pay the interest-only portion of a loan such as a mortgage or student loan.

For example, if you have a mortgage where you're paying $200/month in interest, but you're earning $20 from your bank in the form of interest, would it be okay to pay the $20 towards the $200 interest payment?

Sort of like "fighting fire with fire"

Comment: But then aren't you just using that interest for your own personal benefit? Which in this case, is paying off your own loans. Doesn't seem right to me..